# Switch-Case with multiple Values

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, break

I'm writing a code at the moment where I want to install network-shared printers automatically. Which printer the script should install depends on whether a user works for example in Sales or HR. I wanted to solve this problem with a `switch` statement, but the problem is that it always matches the first value.

I tried several combinations of continue- or break-points, but none of them lead to my desired result.

```
$a = "HR"

switch ($a) {
    {"Marketing", "Sales"}     { "1" }
    {"Sales Department", "HR"} { "2" }
    "EDV"                      { "3" }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Normally, the console output should be "2", but it is "1" "2".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the condition block to:

```
{$_ -in "Marketing", "Sales"}
```

This way both terms will match the switch case

Answer (score 0):

In response to Mathias's answer, couldn't you also use:

```
$a = "HR"
switch($a){
    "Marketing"{}
    "Sales"{"1"; break}
    "Sales Department"{}
    "HR"{"2";break}
}
```

outputs:

> 2

Comment: Yeah, that would work in Theory, but the Code gets long and ugly with it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you put in a scriptblock on the left side, it becomes more like a where clause.

```
 $a | where {"Marketing", "Sales"}
```

Anything returned, like an array of two strings, gets taken as true.  This would return 0 as well:

```
$a = "HR"

switch ($a) {
    {"whatever"}               { "0" }
    {"Marketing", "Sales"}     { "1" }
    {"Sales Department", "HR"} { "2" }
    "EDV"                      { "3" }
}
```

Another way to make it work:

```
$a = "HR"

switch ($a) {
    {$_ -eq "Marketing" -or $_ -eq "Sales"}     { "1" }
    {$_ -eq "Sales Department" -or $_ -eq "HR"} { "2" }
    "EDV"                                       { "3" }
}
```

Or using the -regex option:

```
$a = "HR"

switch -regex ($a) {
    "Marketing|Sales"     { "1" }
    "Sales Department|HR" { "2" }
    "EDV"                 { "3" }
}
```